# MapInfo and Mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I'm looking to run an automation using MapInfo and Mapbasic.

What I want to achieve is to run through a MapInfo table on a row by row basis producing a map for each row within the table and then saving each map as a jpg image on the PC.  I would also like to label each map with a label in the table.  Each map ideally needs to fill the window appropriately as it runs through the query ideally maintaining the size of the map each time.

Is this possible?